# Popup "The software on this computer is up to date" appearing constantly

Tags: 13.04, software-updater

A few days ago the Software Updater started popping "The software on this computer is up to date" every few minutes, even if no update occurred. It's very annoying since the popup steals focus, regardless of what I've done with it previously (selected Ok, closed on the X, ignored).

The Software Updater is set to search for updates daily, downloading and installing security updates automatically, and suggesting only important security and recommended updates.

Does anyone know how to stop the onslaught of pointless dialogs?

I'm using version 13.04, completely updated (as the popup helpfully indicates) and I do have a few extra repositories added to my sources.list file, if that helps.

Comment: Open a terminal by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T** and enter `sudo apt-get update` wait till the flow of text stops. Copy any errors in the end. Again do the same thing with `sudo apt-get upgrade`. **Edit your question and paste all the error messages in the original question above**.

Comment: `upgrade` seems to have fixed the problem, thanks a lot. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you are getting constant popups of "The software on this computer is up to date."

Sometimes trying to achieve the same objective via command line may give us some clue to the actual error (or fix the problem!).

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

wait till the flow of text stops. Copy any errors in the end if any. Then enter:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

wait till the flow of text stops. Copy any errors in the end if any.

If this does not solve the problem, edit the question and include the errors you are getting.

Hope this helps